# Overlapping Jobs in ColdFusion 10 Administrator

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am trying to schedule a job in ColdFusion which basically moves the folders at one location to another. I have scheduled it to run after every 2 mins but it takes more than 2 mins which is depending on the size of the folder.

I noticed one thing that it is executing exactly after two mins skipping the operation it is currently performing.
I want the next run of the job only when the previous run is completed.

Also, I don't know how much time each operation would take as it depends on the size of the folder so probably I cannot make timeout setting or sleep the job for some time. I wanted the dependency in  the previous and next runs of the jobs.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why 2 mins, what is significant about this time, why not 10 mins?

Comment: they upload more folders with more time. So we do it for 10 mins then we have move more. Its just that I wanted to run the next job only when the previous one is completed. @haxtbh

Comment: I tried to schedule a cron time but even with that the next one was triggering before the previous one was completed.

Comment: Are you using windows or linux? I'd be looking to find a faster way for coldfusion task to copy files: if windows are you using robocopy with lots of threads? maybe use system cfexecute to run faster processes either way.

Comment: The first thing in your scheduled task you should check is whether or not your previous operation is finished or not. If not, then just exit the page or request - do not execute if further. 

All your subsequent calls would check if the previous operation is finished or not first before you execute the rest of the logic. That way you are covered for such scenarios with large folder sizes which you can't predict.